# Importing a component into a page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I had created a simple AngularJS component who has as a parameter the title which looks like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function myHeader() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {                
                pageTitle: '@'
            },
            template: '<div class="crumby-title"></div>',
             link: function postlink($scope) {      
                const pageTitle = $scope.pageTitle;
             }
        };
    }

    myHeader.$inject = [];
    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .directive('myHeader', myHeader);
})();
```

I want to use the component into a html page, and I've tried to add it like this:

```
<div class="sample page">
    <my-header page-title="TITLE!"></my-header>
</div>
```

I can see the component in inspect mode but it doesn't appear on the page, also there are no errors. What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't bind the pageTitle to directives template html

directive html should be like that - `template: '<div class="crumby-title">{{pageTitle}}</div>',`

here is running fiddle to play more [Running js fiddle for this demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/2kakSFdGFEEX6WkESpH8?p=info)

Comment: you're using `ng-controller` and other styles that my company's coding standard doesn't accept. I tried the idea you've mentioned by adding `{{pageTitle}}`, but the title doesn't appear on the page, I can see it in inspect mode, the element is there but it isn't visible, same as before

Answer (score 0):

Since you are restricting the directive to be just an element, I would prefer to create a component, which already gives you access to the controller as `$ctrl` and the proper bindings. like this:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
  var HeaderComponent = {
  bindings: {
    pageTitle: '@'
  },
  template: '<div>{{$ctrl.pageTitle}}</div>'
}

 angular.module('myapp', [])
  .component('myHeader', HeaderComponent);
})();
```